# Why does jersey add "@" before my fieldnames?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jersey

I'm glad to post my first question on this site i used so many times before :

I created an index on elasticsearch which works well, but i do not know why, when one of my colleagues uses Jersey to post informations in it (using post on the index to add data and use the auto generated index), we notice new fields have been created with "@" before the fieldname.

For example : I have the field "user" ("type":"string), if my colleague adds a document in the index which use this field, this is the field "@user" which is created.

I discover elasticsearch from few weeks, so maybe the answer is obvious, but my researches did not prove it so far.

I hope i have been clear.

EDIT : I deleted the index and let the jersey code create it, by curiosity. It still created the fields with @ before. It is clearly coming from jersey. I adapted my mapping names to work with it as we need to saves those informations asap. I'll post an answer if i finally find why jersey adds those @.

Comment: Can you show the part of the client code that sends the data to ES?

Comment: No i can not sorry, cause of my colleague's personality :s
i just saw it briefly, this is simple commands in Jersey like target.request([...]).post([...]).